# How can I extract all regions from an image?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, opencv3.0

I have an image like below. Dimension of the image is fixed: `640x480`.

[image]

I want to bound all non-zero regions with rectangles like this:

[image]

I need to know the upper-right, and lower-left points of each of these rectangles.

I have thought about loops and other methods. But all of them will take too long to run. What is the most efficient way to do this in python?

PS: I am a beginner in image processing. This might be an obvious question, i don't know. So giving me a sample code would help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding all sub-components within an image is called [connected component analysis](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Connected-component_labeling). In OpenCV you can do it with `findCountour()` function of its [contour analysis](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html) library.

Here is a sample code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

#=========================================================================
# Locate all components 
#=========================================================================
def locateComponents(img):
    """Extracts all components from an image"""

    out = img.copy()     
    res = cv2.findContours(np.uint8(out.copy()),\
                 cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)    
    contours = res[1]

    ret = []
    row, col = out.shape
    minSiz = 8

    for cnt in contours:
        # get bounding box
        y, x, n, m = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        # check area 
        if m < minSiz or n < minSiz:
            continue
        #end if       

        ret.append(np.int32([x, x+m, y, y+n]))
        out = cv2.rectangle(out, (y,x), (y+n,x+m), (255,255,255), 2)

    #end for

    return ret, out

# end function

#=========================================================================
# TESTING 
#=========================================================================

img = cv2.imread('input.jpg', 0)

regions, out = locateComponents(img)
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', out)
print regions

cv2.imshow('Given image', img)
cv2.imshow('Located regions', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The output image:

[image: The output image]